# Error in using one MapReduce's output as another MapReduce's input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two Map/Reduce classes, named MyMappper1/MyReducer1 and MyMapper2/MyReducer2, and want to use the output of MyReducer1 as the input of MyMapper2, by setting the input path of job2 to the output path of job1.

The types are as follows:

```
    public class MyMapper1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntArrayWritable>
    public class MyReducer1 extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntArrayWritable, IntWritable, IntArrayWritable>
    public class MyMapper2 extends Mapper<IntWritable, IntArrayWritable, IntWritable, IntArrayWritable>
    public class MyReducer2 extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntArrayWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable>

public class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public IntArrayWritable() {
        super(IntWritable.class);
    }
}
```

And the code for setting the input/output path is like:

```
    Path temppath = new Path("temp-dir-" + temp_time);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, temppath);

            ...........

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, temppath);
```

The code for setting Input/Output format is like:

```
    job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
            ..........
    job2.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
```

However I always get the exception when running job2:

```
11/04/16 12:34:09 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0002
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
    at ligon.MyMapper2.map(MyMapper2.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:210)
```

I have tried changing the InputFormat and OutputFormat, but with no success, similar(although not the same) exception happens in job2.

My complete code package is at: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7361939/HW2_Q1.zip

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in job 2, KeyValueTextInputFormat produces key-value pairs of type , and you're attempting to process them with a Mapper that accepts , resulting in a ClassCastException.  Best bet is to change your mapper to accept  and convert from Text to integer.

Comment: Thank you. Now The problem is: ArrayWritable is outputed by the first reducer like below -- there is no element values there---- how to make the second mapper accept this and convert from this string to the object? 


1 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
1 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
2 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
2 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
3 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
3 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
3 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
3 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
4 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21
4 ligon.IntArrayWritable@6659fb21

Comment: I also have the same problem and getting the same error. I want to take use the output of another hadoop job as input for second hadoop job. Output of the first job has MapWritable as value. The solution is job.InputFormatClass() for second job. But which one I should use as parameter

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and figured out the solution few moments ago. Since you are using IntArrayWritable as the output of the reducer its easy to write and later read the data as binary.

For the first job:

```
    job1.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    job1.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(IntArrayWritable.class);
```

For the second job:

```
    job2.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
```

This should work in your case